# Is it possible to insert a custom line as the first line in a log file?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I have created a custom log file for a web service application, where we want to log the time to process requests. We want this in a .csv format, as it would make it easier to read.

I have successfully configured a appender, where I have customized the log output, so it only outputs the date and the message separated by a comma.

```
<log4net>
<appender name="TimingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value=".\\App_Data\\Logs\\" />
      <datePattern value="'GetInstallationsTiming.log_'yyyy-MM-dd'.txt'" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss},%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
<logger name="GetInstallationsTimingLog" addivity="false">
      <level value="All"></level>
      <appender-ref ref="TimingLogFileAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to make a custom line as the first line, that would essentially be the header, so something like date, time in ms, contact email, number of objects?

Comment: Which logger you use ?I mean what you use for logging ?

Comment: I use log4net for logging.

Comment: Are you using the standard RollingFileAppender (log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender). You say 'custom appender', which could be mean that you coded a new type of appender.

Comment: @WulfgarDK if you use log$net you can do this via settings. But also as i coded below you can do easily too. did you have a look to my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the standard RollingFileAppender (log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender). You say 'custom appender', which could be mean that you coded a new type of appender.

The standard RollingFileAppender can be configured with a header like this:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
​    <header type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%newlineLOG START- %env{COMPUTERNAME} - %appdomain - UTC Time: %utcdate Local time: %date %newlineNOTE: All events are logged using UTC time.%newline"/>
```

This will add the following lines to the log each time the application starts:

> LOG START- MyComputer- MyApp.exe - UTC Time: 2019-08-05 12:07:26,641
>   Local time: 2019-08-05 14:07:26,643
>   NOTE: All events are logged using UTC time.

The header text will be added each time logging starts, not just once at the top, so this might not be exactly what you want.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need. And yes, I am indeed using a RollingFileAppender, I have no idea why the first few lines of my config was cut off in my post, I'll edit that when I get back to work tomorrow. My next question would probably be if it isn't possible to start a new log, whenever the application starts, even if it happens twice in the same day?

Comment: Try RollingStyle = Once to get a new file for each program execution.    
   See:   
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use something custom you may write something like this :

```
  public static void Logger(string lines)
    {
        string path = "C:/Log/";
        VerifyYourPath(path);
        string fileName = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() +
       DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "_Logs.txt";
        if (Exist(fileName))// Check you already have this file or not
        {
            // add the new lines to exisiting file
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path + fileName, true);
                var title = DateTime.Now.ToString()/*What you want*/;
                file.WriteLine(title + ": " + lines);
                file.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
```

You can add what you want instead of DateTime.Now.toString(). If you want you can also check it is first line or not.